# Trigger one by one appearance of divs using Framer Motion and Styled Components

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components, framer-motion

I want to create an animation where there are four divs that need to move in view one by one using Framer Motion together with Styled Components. I have created these divs by mapping over them in App.js and they display as Test Components (a dummy name for test purposes). I have tried to use a props named "item" (from an array in App.js with numbers 1, 2, 3, 4) to create a delay between the four different elements. All good and well, except that it does not work.

my code:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const TestItem = styled(motion.div)`
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
`;

const Test = ({item}) => {
    return (
        <TestItem 
            initial={{ y: -200 }}
            whileInView= {{ y: 200}}
            viewport={{ once: true }}
            transition={{
                type: "spring",
                bounce: 0.4,
                duration: 1,
                delay: {item}
            }}
        />
    )
};

export default Test;
```

hope someone can see what's wrong with this code/my thinking?

Answer (score 0):

`delay` expects a number, but you're wrapping the value in an object.

Try
`delay: item`
instead of
`delay: {item}`